# Value error while using AND function in Excel

Tags: excel

In AND function i have passed the cell ranges like this:
AND(A10:A12>9,B10:B12<45) but shows an error. Please help me with this
And the all values in the cells are numbers.

Comment: The problem is the comparison `A10:A12>9`.  Excel doesn't support comparing a range of cells to a single value.  Since it's only 3 cells, just write it out: `AND(A10>9,A11>9,A12>9,B10<45,B11<45,B12<45)`.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have to disagree. `=AND(A10:A12>9,B10:B12<45)` is equivalent to `=AND(A10>9,A11>9,A12>9,B10<45,B11<45,B12<45)`. The former may require committing with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` in earlier versions of Excel, but it is nevertheless equivalent to the latter.

Comment: Please provide more info about error and the sample data or screencap of data used in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

`AND()` function doesn't support array input. Instead, use below function.

```
=(A10:A12>9)*(B10:B12<45)
```

[image]

Comment: `AND` **does** support array *input*. It simply cannot produce an array *output*.